# Keras CNN for multiclass categorical crossentropy loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, convolution

This is my code i typed to classify some classes consisting of birds, dogs and cats. Its the same code for the binary classification but when I add another class and changed the loss function of compile method to use categorical_Crossentropy, it gives me the following error ( => at the end of the code ). can anyone explain what is the issue here or the mistake I have made ?

```
# Importing Keras and Tensorflow modules

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import os.path

# Initilize the CNN

classifier = Sequential()
# Step 1 - Convolution

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 2(b) - Add 2nd Convolution Layer making it Deep followed by a Pooling Layer

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening

classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Fully Connected Neural Network

# Hidden Layer - Activation Function RELU
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')) 
# Output Layer - Activation Function Softmax(to clasify multiple classes)
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compile the CNN

# Categorical Crossentropy - to classify between multiple classes of images
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Image Augmentation and Training Section

# Image Augmentation to prevent Overfitting (Applying random transformation on 
images to train set.ie. 
# scalling, rotating and streching)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=8,
        class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=8,
        class_mode='categorical')

#Fit the clasifier on the CNN data
if(os.path.isfile('my_model.h5') == False):
    classifier.fit_generator(
            training_set,
            steps_per_epoch=8000,
            epochs=2,
            validation_data=test_set,
            validation_steps=2000
                                  )
# Save the generated model to my_model.h5
classifier.save('my_model.h5')
else:
    classifier = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataset seems to have 3 classes so you need to change the last line in a model definition to:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Comment: Thank you! it works I don't know how I missed that, but I'm new to Deep learning ! Appreciate the help !

Answer (score 1):

You need to have one neuron per class on your last (Dense) layer.

```
classifier.add(Dense(3))
```

Right now you have only one neuron and by that your network is still setup for only two classes.